# Rebuilding PIL with FreeType

Tags: python

Previously I got a suggedtion to Install the FreeType dev files and rebuild PIL again.
but I have no idea how to do it.

any help will be thanked for

Comment: Not really a programming question, and depends on what operating system you're using. Linux? Distro?

Answer (score 0):

You do it exactly the same way as you did before, but now with the FreeType-dev files installed.

Comment: It's as helpful as it is possible to be with the given information. Try explaining what you have done, and what you expect to happen, and what happens.